# Standalone keystore works , but if I import that into another keystore, java can't find certificate and fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a keystore in PKCS12 format with 1 certificate in it. It works find with Spring boot app to connect to other spring boot services on other machine using this certificate.  If I import this keystore into other PKCS12 keystore and then use that other keystore for Spring booth java connectivity it fails with below error. Why a keystore with certificate chains in it are ignored here while standlone certificate keystore works fine.

Command to import pkcs12 cert

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Certs\Source_keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass abcdge -srcalias server  -destkeystore C:\Certs\Dest_keystore.p12 -deststorepass abcdge -destalias server -destkeypass abcdge -deststoretype PKCS12
```

I am using openjdk 8 282 keytool.

Spring boot is also running on the same JDK and remote services are also running on the same JDK.

Below is the exception I am getting -

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:927)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1451)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1418)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:335)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1202)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1111)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:398)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.SSLSocketFactoryAdapter.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactoryAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do `keytool -list` on dest_keystore and I bet you'll find it (now) contains two or more privatekey entries. Also get a trace (e.g. with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:keymanager` or by manually connecting with `openssl s_client -debug`) and I bet you'll find that the server is requesting client cert without specifying a CA list, so JSSE chooses which key/cert to use effectively at random and that choice is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you prepare an SSLContext with the trust store for you to use with a RestTemplate? Something like:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
  .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
  .build();
```

Comment: Thanks Dori. Yes I do. And moreover this works when I use src_trustore . Only issue is when I combine with some other trust store by importing.